# Highcharts Drilldown Doesn't Work If Over A Slice When Set Data Called

Tags: highcharts

I am just getting my feet wet with Highcharts and I have ran into an issue. If you have a pie chart with a drill down and your mouse is over a slice and the chart data updates (via setData), the slice goes "inactive". If you try to click the slice to drill down, nothing happens until you mouse off the slice and mouse back on to it. I will be updating values every couple of seconds, so this will become really annoying for users. Here is an example.
http://jsfiddle.net/DSAg7/1/. This is the code that causes the problem:

```
function intervalDataSet(){
                setInterval(function(){                    
                    chart.series[0].setData(brandsData);
                }, 3000);

};
intervalDataSet();
```

Place your mouse over a slice and wait a bit until it goes inactive. Clicking the slice will do nothing until you mouse off and mouse back over it. Is there an option or some sort of chart refresh I am missing that I need to do?

Comment: Looks like a bug, I have reported that on our bug tracker [here](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/3114). Thanks!

Comment: Ok, thank you. I will watch for the fix.